# Positioning Tikz figure with xetex

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

I'd like to write a document using this template : http://phd.epfl.ch/modelesthese.
When i'm compiling with pdflatex, there's no problem and the chapter headers are fine.

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[yshift=-8cm] at (current page.north west)
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[fill=black] (0,0) rectangle(35.5mm,15mm);
    \node[anchor=north west,yshift=-7.2cm,xshift=37mm,text width=\textwidth,minimum height=30mm,inner sep=0mm] at (current page.north west)
    {\parbox[top][30mm][t]{\textwidth}{Chapter One}};
  \end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But with xetex, there is an issue with the chapter header. The position of the text isn't good.

With pdflatex :

[image]

With xelatex :

[image]

Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I compiled the template given [at phd.epfl.ch](http://phd.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/phd/files/shared/0%20Pages%20EDOC/Modeles_these/latex_template5_57.zip) both with pdflatex and xelatex. It produced the same result (after I removed inputenc package for xelatex)

Comment: Are you aware that nesting TikZ pictures is known to cause problems? Sometimes you can get away with it, but often not. Why do you need to nest pictures here? I don't understand the purpose.

Comment: Already an answer is given, but anyway pgf drivers
for XeTeX are known to have bugs, which Ulrike knows better.
For the present example, the following gives the same
results between `pdflatex` and `xelatex`:
`\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{book}`
`\ifx\XeTeXpdffile\undefined\else`
`\newcount\pdftexversion`
`\pdftexversion140`
`\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}`
`\fi`
`\usepackage{tikz}`
`\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}`
`\begin{document}`
`...`
`\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this which avoids nesting pictures? It uses the `positioning` and `calc` libraries to position things:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \coordinate [below=80mm of current page.north west] (a);
    \draw[fill=black] ($(a) + (0,7.5mm)$) rectangle ($(a) + (35.5mm,-7.5mm)$);
    \node[anchor=north west, right=37mm of a, text width=\textwidth, minimum height=30mm, inner sep=0mm]
        {Chapter One};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

[I get the same output with XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX.]

Comment: @user3350813 Don't forget to consider accepting the answer if it solves the problem so that other users can see the question has a solution.